# Best place to put packet class java

Tags: java, packet

I have a game engine class, shared by the client program and the server program.  I have a particular function *updatePlayer(PlayerData data)* which should update a player.  (PlayerData is basically a packet datatype.)

For best standards, where should the PlayerData class go?  Should it be it's own file, in a networking package, or a subclass of a static Packet class?  Normally, I'd make a master namespace(named after my project) in c++ or define the class in my networking class, but you can't define multiple classes in one file in java.

How would you do it?

Comment: I've found this to be an interesting read on the subject of package structure: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Comment: Interesting.  My game engine has a package (no subpackages), but my current project doesn't.  Maybe I should get around organizing things...

Comment: In general it's advised to avoid the default package (that is, no package at all). A good package structure is gonna be a big help in organizing your code. One layer above that, a good partitioning into sub-projects is important. For stuff that's shared on client and server side, you'd definitely want a separate library (i.e. jar file) with the relevant classes. Having separate projects that gradually build on top of each other also promotes code reuse and makes code builds easier.

Answer (score 1):

> For best standards, where should the PlayerData class go?

It should absolutely be in its own file. Nested/inner classes are generally unnecessary in Java.

Comment: Well, ok.  Maybe I should use serialization instead?  I suppose that would make it difficult to tween between packets.

Comment: Serialization? What does that have to do with "where should the PlayerData class go?"

Comment: Instead of a PlayerData class.  Nevermind.  I have it figured out.  Thanks!

Comment: To "serialize" an object is to convert it to a text string suitable for writing to a disk file or transmitting over a communication line, where it can then be converted back into the internal representation of the object. i.e. it is a tool used when saving or transporting objects. It has nothing to do with how you organize your classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "packet" in this context. If my answer seems inapplicable, please clarify.

But in general, in Java if you have several related classes, you should create a package and put the related classes in that package. A "package" in Java is really just a subdirectory that includes all the related .java files.

Don't create a subclass just to group things. That's not what they're for.

If you are coming from another language it might seem like a pain to have to create a separate file for every class. Sure, this can mean that you have to open ten files to see all the related stuff. But on the other hand, it makes it easy to find the right file: just look for the file with that name. And as the file name and the class name must always be the same, we eliminate one name from the list of things we have to comprehend. I've had some minor annoyances with VB where a file name and a class name are subtly different and it's caused me to have to take a few extra minutes to figure it out.